# AVAudioPlayer leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I've got a problem and don't know how to handle it. Tyring to build an app with sound and animation. It gives me a level 1 and then level 2 memory warning. I've tried build and analyze and i got all these potential leaks. If I release theAudio the sound won't play. Any hints?

Here is a part of the code and the leakes I've got

```
    - (IBAction)playsound2
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
        *- **Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference)***
        theAudio.delegate = self;
        [theAudio play];

        ***-  Object allocated on line 302 and stored into 'theAudio' is no longer referenced after this point and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)***


        cat1.hidden = 0;
        cat.hidden = 1;
        [cat1 startAnimating];
        cat.center = cat1.center;
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadAnimations) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        catLabel.hidden = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352588/avaudioplayer-memory-leak) is the solution for the same problem asked so far.

```
    - (AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayerWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path {
        NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        AVAudioPlayer *player = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];
        if([player initWithData:audioData error:NULL]) {
            [player autorelease];
        } else {
            [player release];
            player = nil;
        }
        return player;
    }
```

And for better idea you can follow [**this.**](http://blog.zincroe.com/2009/06/avaudioplayer-memory-leak/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to state an instance variable for the AVAudioPlayer class instance.

```
//Instance variable:
{
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio;
}

- (IBAction)playsound2
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (!theAudio ) {
        theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]; 
        if (theAudio ) {
            theAudio.delegate = self;
            [theAudio play];
        }
    }

    cat1.hidden = 0;
    cat.hidden = 1;
    [cat1 startAnimating];
    cat.center = cat1.center;
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadAnimations) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    catLabel.hidden = 0;
}
```